# Bootstrap accordion with php data and tables on panels

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to insert php datas Inside bootstrap collapse accordion and I meet problems.
I have table in each panel and normally need thead just one time. I've tryed so much 'solutions' and I'm lost.
Please, someone perhaps can help me to code the true way. Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php 
$prod_collection='';
while($prod=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Presults)): 
    if($prod_collection != $prod['prod_collection']): ?>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php echo $prod['prod_collection'] ?>">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $prod['prod_collection'] ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $prod['prod_collection'] ?>">
             <?php echo $prod['prod_collection'] ?>
         </a>
       </h4>
     </div>

 <div id="<?php echo $prod['prod_collection'] ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $prod['prod_collection'] ?>"> 
  <?php endif;?> 
  <div class="panel-body">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-auto table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>Products</th>
        <th>Collection</th>
        <th>In ligne</th>
        <th></th>
        </thead>
       <?php foreach($prod['prod_collection']) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <a href="products.php?edit=<?php echo $prod['idProd'] ?>" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
        <a href="products.php?delete=<?php echo $prod['idProd'] ?>" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo Securite::html($prod['prod_nom']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo Securite::html($prod['prod_collection']); ?></td>
        <td><a href="produits.php?lign=<?php echo (($prod['lign']== 0)?'1':'0') ?>&idProd=<?php echo $prod['idProd'] ?>=" 
        class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<?php echo (($prod['lign']== 1)?'plus':'minus') ?>"></span>
        &nbsp <?php echo (($prod['lign']== 1)?'Products in lign':'Products not in ligne') ?></a></td>

        <td>0</td>                  
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
       </table>
    </div> 

  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Nobody to drive me on the right way ?

Comment: Hi, I reached my aim but a last problem persists.
My table is Inside the while loop and imposible to code thead outside of it cause my collapse titles are dependant of.
So I get as much tables as result.....